# VBA: Splitting and Joining Arrays & Strings

Tags: vba, excel, join, split

I'm dealing with a set of cells that looks something like this:

[image: Cell setup]

What I'm trying to do is filter through the Country column for each country, and then take each of the Mfr's and add them together so that I can filter for them all in another workbook.

So basically, I want to `Join(m1, m2, m3)` and this is how I'm trying to do it:

`xRange` is the column for "Mfr Abbreviation".  I also have `If xCell... <> "" Then` because there are not "Previous Mfr Abbrev" for all entries in `xRange`

```
Dim tempMfr As String
Dim temp2Mfr As String
Dim stringArray() As String
Dim arraytostring As String

For Each xCell In xRange
    tempMfr = xCell

    If xCell.Offset(0, 2) <> "" Then
        temp2Mfr = xCell.Offset(0, 2)
        stringArray() = Split(temp2Mfr, ", ")
        arraytostring = Join(temp2Mfr & stringArray, ", ")
        stringArray() = Split(arraytostring, ", ")


        For x = LBound(stringArray) To UBound(stringArray)
            MsgBox (stringArray(x))
        Next
    End If

Next
```

My issue comes from the line `Join(temp2Mfr & stringArray)` due to the `&` creating a **Type Mismatch** Compile Error.

I've also tried:

```
ReDim Preserve stringArray(0 to (UBound(stringArray) + 1))
stringArray(UBound(stringArray)) = temp2Mfr
```

---

Once I get that sorted out, I plan on using a search in the other workbook that looks something like this:

```
Cells.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= Array(MfrArray)
```

---

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What's the issue? What error are you receiving?

Comment: Type Mismatch; edited original post.  But even so, my method of going about this is what isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are trying to concatenate a string to your array before Join even executes.

That's not permitted and is what is causing your error.

You can do this instead:

```
Redim Preserve stringArray(Ubound(stringArray) + 1)
stringArray(Ubound(stringArray)) = temp2Mfr
```

You do not need Join() at all.

Comment: One error in both of our solutions.  You need `stringArray(Ubound(stringArray) + 1)`  and I needed to get rid of the `0 to`.  But that seems to have done it.  Thank you very much.  Change that and you've got an answer :)

Comment: That's what I get for answering on my phone with no Excel... ;) Fixed the typo.

Comment: As I go to the next entry in that xRange, how do I clear the Array and reset the dimensions?  I'm trying to use `Erase stringArray` and `ReDim stringArray` but Erase leaves no dimensions to work with and ReDim gives a syntax error.

Comment: Try changing your initial declaration of the array to Variant, like so: Dim stringArray As Variant. Notice no parentheses. Then you can create the array within the Variant on the fly by setting it to the results of the Split() function. That should work the first time... and every time subsequently.

Comment: Hey again.  I've been searching around but can't find anything useful.  I need to filter a column for the array I've made with this code.  I'm trying to use `Cells.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=stringArray, Operator:=` but I don't know what the operator should be.  An example of my issue is that something in the Array might be "Ta" when what's in the column is actually "Tawm".  I'm thinking something like `Operator:=xlContains` but that's a no-go.  Do you know how I could do this?  I just want it to be like I'm typing in "Ta" and then selecting all the options which the autofilter finds.

Comment: Please ask this as a new question.

Comment: yeah I figured that would be better.  I posted one.  Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484479/vba-autofilter-for-partial-array-strings