# criteria filter for multiple begin with condition?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=RNG.Column, Criteria1:=Array( _
"=" & "5.*" & "El*", "=" & "4.*" & "El*",  "=" & "3.*" & "El*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I am trying to filter multiple criteria. It takes only 2 criteria at 1 time, but if I add one more criteria it filters nothing. While I have data begin with (5.,4.,3.).

Comment: You can only apply two wildcard filters at one time and not as an array. See [VBA: Autofilter for Partial Array strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484479/vba-autofilter-for-partial-array-strings/31484831#31484831)

Comment: thanks ..now i got it..

Answer (score 0):

In this respect the VBA limitation is the same as in the worksheet:

[image: SO34062016 example]

A workaround (for the sake of others if not the OP) is to add a column with a flag that is derived from a formula that captures as many selections as required. For the example above this might be (assuming the column to be filtered is ColumnB):

```
=AND(OR(LEFT(B3,2)="3.",LEFT(B3,2)="4.",LEFT(B3,2)="5."),SEARCH("El",B3,3)>0)
```

and then filter on the flag column, with code such as:

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=RNG.Column, Criteria1:="TRUE"
```